# Adding characters to string in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, substring

I had a table called Name with employee names formatted as `Lastname, Firstname`. I switched them around so it would be `Firstname Lastname`.

However, there are names like "Zorro" and "Jessia Kim" that were not effected by this because they did not have a comma. Instead, I need to put a "!" in front of them so the admin could change them later. Is there any way I could add "!" to those kinds of names in the SELECT statement?

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) + 1, LEN(Name)) + ' ' +
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Name)),',','') AS NewName
FROM Employees
```

The right side is what it should look like.
[image: reference]

Comment: What's wrong with `'!' + {name}`? Why didn't what you tried not work?

Comment: So "Jessia Kim" is still in "Lastname, Firstname" order and was not switched when the comma's were removed?  You have backups?

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
select 
    case when charindex(',', name) > 0
        then substring(name, charindex(',', name) + 1, len(name)) 
            + ' ' 
            + substring(name, 1, charindex(',', name) - 1) 
        else '!' + name
    end as newname
from employees
```

Basically, this checks whether the `name` contains a comma; if it does, then it switches both parts, as you intended too. If it doesn't, then it concatenates `!` at the beginning of the string.

Note that I optimized a little the logic that inverts the first and last name - I don't think you need `replace()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX(',',Name)<=0, '!'+Name,
          SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) + 1, LEN(Name)) + ' ' +
          REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Name)),',','')
        )
```